# How to use an upto method in ruby to count up by 100?

Tags: ruby, loops, methods

I need to make a program that counts down from 10, displays a message, and then immediately after starts counting from 100 metres to 200 metres, and so on up to 100,000 metres. I can't figure out how to do the last part. This is the code I have so far.

```
10.downto(1) do|counter| 
    puts counter 
    sleep 1
end 

puts "Blast off!"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in increments of 100, try this:

```
100.step(100_000, 100) {|c| puts c; sleep(0.5)}
```

Comment: Yep, use `step`: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Numeric/step

Comment: It says syntax error when I add that to my current code.. ?

Comment: @AliceAuburn: what's the error?

Comment: I don't know it opens too quickly to read more. Ruby quickly opens, for like half a second and then closes when I try to open the program. When it opens I can read it says "syntax error" but nothing else.

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out thanks! :)